# How to Handle Multiple Environments in a React App with Azure DevOps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-devops

Devs out there,
I am having a little issue while trying to setup multiple environment in my react project using Azure DevOps. There is not much info out there on how you can get this done and I can see to get it right.

I want to have the:

- Development
- Production

At the moment I have it implement as such on my React app:

src > service > JS instance.js > instance

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://xxx-test.azurewebsites.net/api',
  // baseURL: 'https://localhost:5001/api',
})

export default instance
```

My script looks like this, and I have not changed to the script under package.json:

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.env file mechanism](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env):

Add a `.env` file with:

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=https://localhost:5001/api
```

And modify your code:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import config from './config'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
})

export default instance
```

Now, in the pipeline, you need to set `REACT_APP_API_URL` env variable differently depending on your target environment. You can use [pipeline variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline) for that (because they are also exposed as env variables). In yaml, it could look like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: test
    variables:
      REACT_APP_API_URL: https://xxx-test.azurewebsites.net/api
    jobs:
      - job: test_job
        steps:
          - script: npm run build
          # then deploy the app however you want
  - stage: prod
    variables:
      REACT_APP_API_URL: https://xxx-prod.azurewebsites.net/api
    jobs:
      - job: prod_job
        steps:
          - script: npm run build
          # then deploy the app however you want
```

Comment: Hey qbik, first of all! Thank you for that, very nice indeed. You worked nicely, you gave the the direction to get it fixed. Appreciate the help. ✔