# Separate CI/CD Workflow Yml for Staging and Prod without Merging for an Azure hosted Static Web App

Tags: yaml, github-actions, cicd, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to have separate environment variables, in this case, API strings for the staging and prod branches of my front end SPA.

```
REACT_APP_APIURL="somethingsomething.com"
```

They are defined within .env files:

```
.env.production
.env.staging
```

I've defined scripts in the `package.json` to use those files depending on the custom build command:

```
"build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build",
"build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
```

So each branch has different `azure-static-web-apps.yml` file with a different `app_build_command:`:

Branch: Staging

```
app_build_command: "npm run build:staging"
```

Branch: Prod

```
app_build_command: "npm run build:production"
```

**But upon merging staging and prod in Github, I'll be forced to merge the `azure-static-web-apps.yml` file preventing me from having 2 separate build configurations for the 2 staging and prod environments. I don't want this**

I've looking into Templates:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops
But it doesn't seem to be useful for this case.

This there a way to do this?

Comment: Looks like there's an instance where is problem is solved using Azure DevOps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68035577/how-to-handle-multiple-environments-in-a-react-app-with-azeru-devops

Is using Azure DevOps the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically get the current branch name, e.g., from `$GITHUB_REF`, and pass that to your build command.  Then ensure your npm command in package.json matches.

[How to get the current branch within Github Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033366/how-to-get-the-current-branch-within-github-actions/58034787#58034787)